# jq parsing json out of json values

Tags: bash, shell-script, jq

I have something like the following

```
echo "{\"t\":\"set foo='{\\\"mode\\\":1}'\"}"|jq .
{
  "t": "set foo='{\"mode\":1}'"
}
```

and I'd like the output to look something like

```
{
  "t": "set foo='{\"mode\":1}'",
  "mode": 1
}
```

Right now I am making several execs to make this happen and would like to see if its possible into one jq call.

Comment: It's unclear why you can't just add the `"mode": 1` bit to our `echo`.

Comment: It sounds more like testing challenge, but it shouldn't be treated as applicable and practical example. I can present a solution, but the point is that you need to manage your input to not get into such fragile pipes

Comment: This is an example of a real world example. In this case there is no control over the input, for it is a complex pipe.

Answer (score 1):

For this exact input,

```
jq '. + (.t[9:-1] | fromjson)'
```

will do what you want. It extracts characters `{"mode":1}` [from the string (starting at 9, omitting the last one)](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/#.[%3Cstring%3E],.[2],.[10:15]) so that it leaves off the single quotes on both sides, then [parses it as JSON](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/#Convertto/fromJSON) into an object with `fromjson`, and finally merges that object (`{"mode": 1}`) with the original input ([`.`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/#.)) [using `+`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/#Addition-+).

You will need to adjust the indices to match your real data. If you need to find where the opening `'` is, `(.t|index("\u0027")+1)` will work as a replacement for `9`; if you need to parse it out more thoroughly, ask a fresh question.

Comment: This didn't work out of the back but I'll fiddle around some.

Comment: The comment you posted pre-edit seemed to show it working and the output is verbatim what's in the question; if it's *not* what you wanted, you can [edit] the question to say what you actually wanted

Comment: You are correct, I misread the output. This ended up working fine along with some other tweaks. Thanks again!